# find find with file name as variable in glob

Tags: python, glob

I want to delete specific files from a list of csv files.

the file name is something like this: Storm.abc.ibtracs_all.v03r10.csv. where abc is different for each file.

I have a list of the abc part (namely tmp2) of the files that I want to delete.

my idea is to loop through the list above with the file name as variable and pass it to glob to get the file name that matches and then delete it

```
import glob

 for i in range(len(tmp2)):

name=tmp2[i]

files=glob.glob('*.name.*')

os.remove(files)
```

I doesnt work obviously. please help with the treatment of glob.glob('*.name.*')

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

```
import glob
import os

path = "YourPath"
for i in tmp2:                              #Iterate Your List
    files=glob.glob('*.{}.*'.format(i))     #Check for files
    for file in files:               
        fPath = os.path.join(path, file)    #Form full path to file
        os.remove(fPath)                    #Remove
```