# How to iterate through directories with specific string

Tags: python

I am attempting to identify specific subfolders within a directory containing a specific string.

For example: I have a series of folders that all have a year in the name. I would like to identify all folders with the year 2020 in the name and run my script on those specific folders.

My end result: I am attempting to calculate the total size of .mp4 files for all folders within a specific year (eg. 2020).

What I have: I have a piece of code that allows me to calculate the size of all files of a specific file type within a folder. This piece of code works as intended.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

total_file_size = 0
# get file path
for path in Path('C:\Users\individual folder with .mp4').rglob('*.MP4'):
    # get size of file
    Path(path).stat()
    file_size = Path(path).stat().st_size
    #print(file_size)
    total_file_size += file_size
print(total_file_size)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find find with file name as variable in glob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626666/find-find-with-file-name-as-variable-in-glob)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm sure this question has been answered before, it's [one of these posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+glob+name+pathlib). Please see the [search page in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

Comment: Hi bad_coder, I am not seeing any specific cases where users are identifying specific directories to run .rglob on.

Comment: Why do you want to use rglob to do that? You could check something like `'2020' in path.name`, else skip everything else

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, I am using .rglob to find all .mp4 files. I could probably use your suggestion to identify folders then use what I have already to gather all specific file types.

Comment: Sure, or you could use `glob('*2020*.mp4')` as the linked post says